# Can I format my code to this style using clang-format?

Tags: c++, coding-style, clang-format

```cpp
class A                     {
    int a                   ;
public                      :
    A(int a)                :
        a(a)                {}
    int get_a()             {
        return a            ;}
                            };
int main()                  {
    A a(1)                  ;
    cout << a.get_a()       ;}
```

Can I format my code to this style using clang-format?

Comment: What happens when you have a line of code with `length > 30` ?

Comment: No, there are no options in the current version of clang-format that support such "style"

Comment: For those not understanding the purpose of this style, it seems clear that the goal is to make C++ look like Python or a similar scripting language that has no statement terminals or grammar explicitly denoting block scope by shoving them off to the side of the screen. Now, this is obviously a bad idea, because pretending that a language which has these features doesn't is trying to lie to the reader, but that's the goal of the thing.

Comment: @YSC: That all depends on how you interpret the statement in the downvote help text. Some might say that doing research into C++ would tell you not to want to format text this way. Some might say that, because the goal of the question is bad, it is a priori not useful.

Comment: In addition to @YSC's comment, also remember that you shouldn't vote based on a question's score. For example you shouldn't upvote simply because you feel a question has too many downvotes. See [Is it wrong to use an upvote to balance out a downvote?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/311406/is-it-wrong-to-use-an-upvote-to-balance-out-a-downvote).

Answer (score 3):

> Can I format my code to this style using clang-format?

No, you cannot.

clang-format has no option to help you format your code this way since this style is quite unique (by *unique* I don't mean *good*, quite the opposite).